# L in P/Poly but L not in P

Tags: complexity-theory

> Show that there is a squatting language L:

```
L in P/Poly but L not in P
```

I'd like to read your explanations

Comment: Proving such a thing would imply that you have a language L in NP that is not in P. Since the status of P vs NP is still unproven, it is unclear how to proceed with such a process. Is there any way in which you would like to qualify the request?

Comment: Is this the definition of _squatting language_?